# How to access and modify values of variables in matlab workspace?

Tags: matlab

There are few variables in my matlab workspace, lets say a and b. 
eg: a = 1:5;
b = 1:10;

I used `who` to get their names.

like  `listVariables = who;`

now `listVariables` has the variable names `a` and `b`, but i dont know how to access their values so that I can do some mathematical operations on them.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend to do this at all, however, check the `eval` function of matlab (`eval(listVariables(1).name)`)

Comment: May I ask what the use-case is? I mean, why would you do mathematical operations on variables you do not know?

Comment: @NickyMattsson, I am using matlab filter design tool and it has an option to import the coefficients designed in the tool to the workspace. on these coefficients i want to do some fixed point conversion,scaling etc

Comment: Arent the variables names predefined, meaning they always will be the same?

Comment: The names can be changed during export. Maybe saving to mat and loading a strict is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [evalin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) is what your are searching for:

```
a_val = evalin('base', listVariables{1});
b_val = evalin('base', listVariables{2});
```

---

The advantage of `evalin` is that it can be executed from a function (out of the scope of the workspace).

Example:

In workspace:

```
a = 1:5; b = 1:10;
```

Content of `my_fun.m`:

```
function my_fun()

listVariables = evalin('base', 'who');

a_val = evalin('base', listVariables{1});
b_val = evalin('base', listVariables{2});

display(a_val);
display(b_val);
```

Result of `my_fun()` execution:

```
a_val =

     1     2     3     4     5


b_val =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Note: there are cases in which `evalin` is useful, but it's not a good coding practice.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, Thank you